# Scale and translate transformations on a matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, windows-phone, transformation

I am currently trying to port the following Java or Swift code in C# (in a Windows Phone library) :

Here the Java code :

```
public Matrix zoom(float scaleX, float scaleY, float x, float y) 
{
 final Matrix save = new Matrix();
 save.set(anotherMatrix);
 save.postScale(scaleX, scaleY, x, y);
 return save;
}
```

And here the Swift code :

```
public func zoom(#scaleX: CGFloat, scaleY: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform
{
  var matrix = CGAffineTransformTranslate(_touchMatrix, x, y);
  matrix = CGAffineTransformScale(matrix, scaleX, scaleY);
  matrix = CGAffineTransformTranslate(matrix, -x, -y);
  return matrix;
}
```

Basically, in C# for Windows Phone I have the following classes :

- `System.Windows.Media.Matrix`
- `System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform`
- `System.Windows.Media.ScaleTransform`

But... the `Transform` method of the `TranslateTransform` and `ScaleTransform` classes work with `Point` and not with `Matrix`.

How can I apply scale and translate transformation to a matrix in C# ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636081/how-to-rotate-scale-and-translate-a-matrix-all-at-once-in-c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636081/how-to-rotate-scale-and-translate-a-matrix-all-at-once-in-c).

Comment: @JohnOdom : Thx for your help. It it not a duplicate. In fact, The `System.Windows.Media.Matrix` class does not provide `Scaling` or `Translation` method. But the `Matrix` from the Xna namespace seems to has these methods. Should I use this class ? Xna is deprecated isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution :

```
var tt1 = new TranslateTransform(x,y);
var matrix=_touchMatrix* tt1.Value;

var sc=new ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY);
matrix = matrix *sc.Value;

var tt2 = new TranslateTransform(-x,-y);
matrix =matrix*tt2.Value ;
```

Answer (score 0):

What @john-odom is trying to say is that you need to multiply two transforms together in order to apply their combined effect on a Point. The [Matrix.Multiply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.multiply(v=vs.110).aspx) method will help you do what you need, the link to the XNA-based answer wasn't to point you to those specific types/libraries but make you aware of the principle behind it, instead.

Comment: Thx for your help. Unfortunately, I do not have access to all the methods describe in this documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.matrix%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Basically, after instantiate a matrix like this `var matrix = new Matrix()` the auto-completion does not provide the `scale` method...

Comment: That's what I'm saying. You can't use `System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform` and `System.Windows.Media.ScaleTransform`. You need to use `System.Windows.Media.Matrix` along with the [Translate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.translate(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Scale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.scale(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

Comment: But In Windows Phone  these methods do not exist : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.media.matrix%28v=vs.105%29.aspx Anyway, I have post the solution.